# While loop for 10 seconds with blocking

Tags: python, time, blocking

I have a loop that should run for 10 seconds only, but inside the loop I'm using a blocking function, so the loop doesn't break after 10 seconds, but only after blocking function.

```
endtime = time.time() + 10 

while time.time() < endtime:
    clientsocket, address = tcpServer.accept()  # blocking
    print("got another client!")
    name = clientsocket.recv(1024)

print("bye")
```

I want to leave the loop after 10 seconds, but if I got into it before 10 seconds passed and no one is trying to connect I'm not getting out.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please explain. What do you mean by "got into it before 10 seconds and no one is connecting" ?

Answer (score 2):

You should set timeout in tcp instance before while like below:

```
tcpServer.settimeout(10)
```